# Android Saving data on Button

Tags: android

I have a button in a customView which has several numbers  on it individually,it counts backward 
now my program doesn't keep value on it when user taps back and closes the program How can I prevent this ?

Comment: show some code please

Comment: do you want to save the data?

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
         
              btnNum[position]--;
                if(btnNum[position]==0){
                    button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                } it just decrements number on the button

Comment: you can Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) its easy to write and get.

Comment: yes I want to save the data

Comment: check the answer..you can do it with sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value from one activity to other using intents. If you want to persist data,the simplest way to achieve this would be saving it in `Shared Preferences`.

Developer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) has good information on how to implement this -

You can save the value Key, Value pair and then retrieve it when the app is up again.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) its easy to write and get.

You can create one like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("yours", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and write to like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor=prefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putString("what you want", "value of what you want");
prefsEditor.apply();
```

and retrive like this

```
String s=prefs.getString("what you want", "value to be retrived if failur happens in retreiving")
```

Comment: ıf we have numbers on the button how are going to handle is it the same process ?

Comment: Do you mean Integer instead of String?

Comment: prefsEditor.putInt("what you want", 1);

and prefs.getInt("what you want",0);

just replace String by Int

Comment: @ARKA Mark my answer if you found it useful

Comment: I am using Custom view the problem is that I cannot initialize inside the Adapter so I can't use  Shared Preferences How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

if the value **not important** after end the program you can save it into **public static variable**

but if you need the variable after end the program you can use **SharedPreferences**

follow this tutorial http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html